# The problem about code in Exploitation technique

Tags: c, assembly

I am newbie and learned of an exploit while reading some document, I see some problem with this code. It's not related to what I'm learning in school.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char **argv ){

long ebp;

asm ( "movl %%ebp, %0\n" :"=r"(ebp) );
printf( "Current ebp: 0x%x\n", ebp ),
return 0;
}
```

My question:
`asm ( "movl %%ebp, %0\n" :"=r"(ebp) )`>>> What is its impact on the enforcement program and debug with gdb?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I tried helping with grammar, I hope I interpreted your intent correctly.

Comment: This code prints out the current content of the EBP register. A relatively meaningless value without further context.

Comment: There is no impact on anything from this.  You can debug this program with GDB as normal, with either source view or disassembly view.